# StreamReader.ReadLineAsync getting stuck

Tags: c#

I want to make a project where I have a `TcpListener` and a `TcpClient` in which the client sends command(s) to the listener to handle and then returns the client a result. When I run my code with debugger everything works fine, the stream reader reads the stream but when I don't debug it, it hangs on the stream reader in `ReadResponse`,

```
 //server
public async void StartListening()
{
    running = true;
    listener = new TcpListener(settings.publicIP, settings.port);
    listener.Start();

    while (running)
    {
        var tcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        HandelClient(tcpClient);
    }
}

private async void EventListener()
{
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        try
        {
            string response = await ReadCmd(stream);
            await WriteResponse(response, stream);
        }
        catch 
        { 
            throw new Exception(); 
        }
    }
}

private async Task<string> ReadCmd(NetworkStream stream)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
    {
        string sentEvent = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        return CommandHandler.ExecuteCommandAsAdmin(sentEvent.Substring(4));
    }
}

private async Task WriteResponse(string response, NetworkStream stream)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true))
    {
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(response);
        await writer.FlushAsync();
    }
}

//client
public async Task StartConnection()
{
    await client.ConnectAsync(settings.server.IP, settings.server.port);
    connected = true;
    //streamThread.Start();
}
public async Task<string> ExecuteCommand(string cmd)
{
    if (client.Connected)
    {
        using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            await WriteCommand(cmd, stream);
            string res = await ReadResponse(stream);
            return res;
        }
    }

    return "client not connected";
}

public async Task WriteCommand(string cmd, NetworkStream stream)
{
    using (StreamWriter eventSender = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true))
    {
        await eventSender.WriteLineAsync(ConnectionHandler.BuildCmd(cmd));
        await stream.FlushAsync();
    }
}

public async Task<string> ReadResponse(NetworkStream stream)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string name = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Important: you should *not* create more than one `StreamReader` on the same `Stream` - the `StreamReader` *over-reads* (so that it doesn't have to read one byte at a time), and keeps a cache of some data internally; if you create more than one reader: this data is lost, leaving your data stream in an undefined state; it *looks* like you're actually only sending/receiving one message per stream, so you *might* get away with this, but... dangerous way of writing it.

Comment: Additional: `async void` screams "bad things"; I understand what you're trying to express there, but: *just by existing*, that is bad (it is literally enough, by itself, to crash an application - at least, with some sync-context implementations); as is the `catch { throw new Exception(); }` - maybe if you logged the exception there it might tell you about a problem?

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you! I'll try taking your advice. and can you clarify about the two stream readers? how can I not create two different stream? cause it's two different projects, is there a way to use the same stream reader in two different project? I'm not sure I fully understood what you meant when using only one stream reader. Thanks!

Comment: in the code shown, you're only reading one command; often, people want to read *multiple* commands - *that* is when it becomes a problem; meaning: you couldn't take the code above and use it to handle multiple frames

Comment: ok I found a solution for my code. for some reason (I still don't understand why) if I changed the function "ReadResponse" to be not async.